# RETURNN Custom Layer Search Mode Assertion Error

Tags: tensorflow, returnn

I've implemented a custom RETURNN layer ([HMM Factorization](https://github.com/nikita68/returnn/blob/master/TFNetworkHMMFactorization.py)), which works as intended during training, but throws an assertion error when used in search mode. The output of the layer is identical to that of a softmax layer.

Here's the config that was used : [transformer + HMM Factorization](https://github.com/nikita68/NMT/blob/master/hmm-factorization/en-de/transformer-hmm)

This was tested using the latest version of RETURNN.

The exact line that fails is ([code link](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/blob/ae50b3aba732c69dc763c12d7b27d6572f3694de/TFNetworkRecLayer.py#L1459)):

```
assert fixed_seq_len is not None
```

Here's the [full error log](https://pastebin.com/80fChSVS) (too large to paste here)

Here's the [training initialisation](https://pastebin.com/5kPx62Xi)

Does anybody have any ideas what the error could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a bug in RETURNN. I created a pull request [here](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/pull/90) which should fix that, and merged that in now.

The problem was not with your custom layer, but rather with a layer inside your RecLayer, which was actually totally independent, i.e. this one:

```
'encoder_int': {'activation': None,
                'class': 'linear',
                'from': ['base:encoder'],
                'n_out': 1000,
                'with_bias': False}
```

It just depends on one base layer (`"base:encoder"`), nothing else. So it (correctly) optimize this layer out of the recurrent loop, because it is independent.

However, then it sees that you are accessing this layer inside the loop, and as this is a loop over time, it assumes that this loop is over this time-dimension of `"base:encoder"`. Then it tries to unroll the `"base:encoder"` (`TensorArray.unroll`) given the seq len of the rec layer, but then it fails because at this time it does not know the seq len of the rec layer.

My fix now does some more advanced check whether this assumption is correct, i.e. that the loop is really over the same time dimension. The check is a bit fragile though, and not sure if that works correctly in all cases. However, I created a test case which reproduces your problem and this is fixed now.